# Android Emulator not launching devices

Tags: android-emulator

I'm trying to launch android emulator on android studio.
However, every time I create a device, it fails launching and I have the error message "The emulator process for [name] has terminated."

I tried creating different machines but none worked.
The computer I'm running it on seems to have free space, where could the problem come from ?